# Components rendered in a FlatList are rerendered even if they are declared as PureComponent and their props references have not been changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, immutability

I'm working on a react native application with redux in which I'm fetching posts as pages each page holds 5 posts and render them in a FlatList. When the Home screen is rendered I fetch the first page of posts and concatinate them with the, initially, empty posts array in the store. When the user scrolls down, I go and fetch the next page of posts and concatinate them with the posts array. The problem is that on fetching the next page of posts and concatinate them with the existing posts array, I notice that existing posts from the previous pages that are already rendered in the FlatList are rerendered. I detect that through logging in the componentDidUpdate lifecycle method.

Here is how I render the posts FlatList in home screen:

```
renderPostsList = () => {
        const { posts, onFetchPosts, postsComments } = this.props;

        return(
            <FlatList 
              style = { styles.postsList }
              keyExtractor = { item => item.id.toString() }
              onEndReachedThreshold = { 0.5 }
              onEndReached = { ({distanceFromEnd}) => { onFetchPosts() } }
              data = { posts }
              renderItem = { ({ item }) => { 
                  return(
                      <Post 
                        userName = { item.user.username }
                        time = { item.created_at }
                        content = { item.onlyText }
                        commentsCount = { item.commentCount }
                        likesCount = { item.likeCount }
                        dislikesCount = { item.dislikeCount }
                        sharesCount = { item.shareCount }
                        comments = { postsComments.get( item.id ) }
                        fetchCommentsHandler = { this.getFetchCommentsHandlerForPost( item ) }
                      />
                  );  
                }
              }  
            />
        );
};
```

Here is the `getFetchCommentsHandlerForPost` method:

```
getFetchCommentsHandlerForPost = post => {
      return () => {
        if ( post.commentCount > 0 ) {
          this.props.onFetchComments( post.id );
        }
      };
};
```

Here is `onFetchPosts` Action creator:

```
export const fetchPosts = () => ( dispatch, getState ) => {
    const { nextPage } = getState().posts;

    if ( !nextPage ) {
        return;    
    }

    dispatch( startLoading() );

    const user = getState().auth.user.user;

    const userId = user
        ? user.id
        : null;

    axios( '/posts', {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
            userId,
            page: nextPage
        }
    } )
    .then( res => {
        const posts = res.data.data.map( item => {
            if ( !item.user ) {
                item.user = { username: 'No Name' };
            }

            return item;
        } );

        dispatch( appendPosts( posts ) );

        const { current_page, last_page } = res.data.meta;
        const nextPage = current_page === last_page? null : current_page + 1;
        dispatch( updateNextPage( nextPage ) );

        dispatch( stopLoading() );            
    } )
    .catch( err => {
        dispatch( stopLoading() );
        dispatch( setError( i18n.t( 'errors.fetch_posts_failed' ) ) )
    } );
};
```

Here is posts reducer:

```
import { APPEND_POSTS,
    START_LOADING,
    STOP_LOADING,
    POSTS_SET_ERROR,
    POSTS_CLEAR_ERROR,
    UPDATE_NEXT_PAGE } from '../actions/ActionTypes';

const initialState = {
    posts: [],
    nextPage: 1,
    isLoading: false,
    error: null
};

const postsReducer = ( state = initialState, action ) => {
    switch( action.type ) {
        case APPEND_POSTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: state.posts.concat( action.payload.posts )
            };
        case UPDATE_NEXT_PAGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                nextPage: action.payload.nextPage
            };
        case START_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true
            };
        case STOP_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false
            };
        case POSTS_SET_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload.error
            };
        case POSTS_CLEAR_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: null
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default postsReducer;
```

Since FlatList as well as my `Post` component are `PureComponent`, I expect that existing posts have the same reference in the previous and new post array so they should not get rerendered.

Comment: how did you find that entire Flatlist is rerendering?

Comment: `I detect that through logging in the componentDidUpdate lifecycle method` of `Post` component

Comment: Hmm, Check out my answer

Comment: I replied there @KiranManiya

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to add a `key` to your `Post`s:

```
<Post 
    key = {item.id}                        
    userName = { item.user.username }
    time = { item.created_at }
    content = { item.onlyText }
    commentsCount = { item.commentCount }
    likesCount = { item.likeCount }
    dislikesCount = { item.dislikeCount }
    sharesCount = { item.shareCount }
    comments = { postsComments.get( item.id ) }
    fetchCommentsHandler = { this.getFetchCommentsHandlerForPost( item ) }
 />
```

Now React can tell which items are new and which were there previously.

Comment: The ` keyExtractor ` prop of ` FlatList ` is responsible for mapping the ` key ` prop needed to an attribute in ` item ` object which is ` id ` in my case. Refer to this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#keyextractor

Comment: Does adding a key not make any difference? That link you posted says that if you don't provide a custom keyExtractor then `The default extractor checks item.key, then falls back to using the index, like React does.`

Comment: I already provided a custom ` keyExtractor ` . Look at the the ` FlatList ` component I rendered above.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `FlatList` to render dynamic or paginated data from REST API, You should not use FlatList as PureComponent. PureComponent should not have state and that's why entire Component going to be re-render when props changes. You can use `Post` as a PureComponent but not an entire `FlatList` here. Give it a try and don't use `FlatList` as PureComponent. Use `Post` as PureComponent with Component `Key` as `key = {postitem.id}`.

When the Component is used as a pure component, it does not hold any state and here in your case `FlatList` is PureComponent so as soon as the Data changes, it calls the render function for that `FlatList` and it entirely re-rendred.

Comment: `PureComponent should not have state` Since when?

Comment: If I'm not going to use ` FlatList ` what should I use?

Comment: I'm not saying to not to use FlatList, I'm Saying that use Flatlist as Stateful component rather than Pure one. PureComponent does have state, but here you are not using the state in Post Component. Use the FLatList as Stateful Component and Post as PureComponent with state rather passing props.
if you still stuck, let me know. I will share the code snippet.